# $\mathbb E[X]$ and $Var[X]$ for $X=IB$

Tags: probability

Determine $\mathbb E[X]$ and $Var[X]$ for $X=IB$ where $I\sim Ber(p), p>0$ and $B$ with $\mathbb P[B=b]=1$ for some $b>0$ are independent.

> I was wondering why the author makes the assumption $b>0$ here.

We simply have $\mathbb E[X]=\alpha b$ and $\mathbb E[X^2]=\alpha b^2$ (and can use this to determine the variance) or am I missing something?

Comment: $B$ behaves like a constant multiplier for $I$ so your answer is correct.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri But do we really need $b>0$?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it is only a typo but

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=pb$$

I do not know where $\alpha$ comes from

Same observation for the second simple moment